# What is the DNS entry for the Google Play store?

Tags: google-play-store

What is the DNS entry for the Google Play store?

I ask because I could not get anything to update or install.  After trying everything, I could not get anything to work.  Then, I turned off wifi, and it updated on the 3g/4g connection.
I found a post about DNS entry.
After changing the DNS server, it now downloads.  So, what is the DNS name of the Play store?

Answer (score 1):

The Google PlayStore app mainly the following URL:

https://android.clients.google.com

Additional servers may be used for login or downloading the description and images shown within the PlayStore app.

Also the actual download URL points to one of a large number of servers in the Google Content Delivery Cloud (actually you can say it is more or less random from your point of view).